# Windows QoS and DSCP values

Tags: windows, qos, windows-networking

I see QoS Scheduler is in the adapter properties.

Does QoS Scheduler in Windows prioritizes traffic with `DSCP EF bit` by default (without QoS policy)?

Comment: Do you know whether or not this is an OS function or a hardware driver function? I would guess, considering that it is in the Adapter Properties, that it is likely a driver function. What network adapter do you have?

Comment: As per my research, Quality of Service (QoS) scheduling is an operating system (OS) function in Windows 10 that affects how data is prioritized and scheduled for processing on the network interface. This applies to both physical and virtual network adapters, including those used by VPN clients.

I have a VPN client adapter (PaloAlto GP) with the QoS Scheduled "checked" in properties